# Conceptual query with Getaddrinfo method

Tags: winsock2, getaddrinfo

When using the getaddrinfo method, I'm providing an IP address and the port number. I'm getting a linked list in the out variable. It works fine. But I have a conceptual doubt here. When i am giving both the IP address and port, how is it there are so many possible sockets returned? Shouldnt there be only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the getaddrinfo man page:

> There are several reasons why the linked list may have more than one
>   addrinfo structure, including: the network host is multihomed,
>   accessible over multiple protocols (e.g. both AF_INET and AF_INET6);
>   or the same service is available from multiple socket types (one
>   SOCK_STREAM address and another SOCK_DGRAM address, for example).
>   Normally, the application should try using the addresses in the order
>   in which they are returned. The sorting function used within
>   getaddrinfo() is defined in RFC 3484; the order can be tweaked for a
>   particular system by editing /etc/gai.conf (available since glibc
>   2.5).

Comment: got that. But the structures returned are not compatible with sockaddr_storage. My question is with reference to that structure.